# Swift- Drag Button from one Position to Another

Tags: swift

I am trying to drag a button from one position to other using UITouch. But I'm not able to drag it . I'm facing problem in adding button target...

My code-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     let btn_swap = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton!
    btn_swap .setTitle("Drag Me", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn_swap.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    btn_swap.addTarget(self, action: "wasDragged:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)

    btn_swap.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.bounds.size.width - 100)/2.0,
        (self.view.bounds.size.height - 50)/2.0,
        100, 50)

    self.view.addSubview(btn_swap)
    self.creation_of_btn()
 }

func wasDragged (buttn : UIButton, event :UIEvent)
{
    var touch : UITouch = event.touchesForView(buttn) . anyObject() as UITouch
    var previousLocation : CGPoint = touch .previousLocationInView(buttn)
     var location : CGPoint = touch .locationInView(buttn)
    var delta_x :CGFloat = location.x - previousLocation.x
      var delta_y :CGFloat = location.y - previousLocation.y
    buttn.center = CGPointMake(buttn.center.x + delta_x,
        buttn.center.y + delta_y);

}
```

Comment: thanks for code for delta, it's great

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You given a wrong selector for your button `wasDragged:`. Since your action method look's like

```
func wasDragged (buttn : UIButton, event :UIEvent)
{
}
```

slector should be `wasDragged: event:`.

```
btn_swap.addTarget(self, action: "wasDragged:event:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDragInside)
```

Comment: it is working bro... thanks.. Please edit and remove space between wasDragged:event:

Comment: hi i done it in swift3. but how i detect end position because i want to re-set button at his postion?

Answer (score 0):

Event TouchDragInside also needs event argument needs to be passed as the second argument.

Swift 1 :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24547115/5078763

Swift 2 :

```
btn_swap.addTarget(self,action: #selector(wasDragged(_:event:)),forControlEvents: .TouchDragInside)

func wasDragged(btnVar : UIButton, evtVar :UIEvent)
{
    let touch : UITouch = (evtVar.touchesForView(btnVar)?.first)! as UITouch
    let previousLocation : CGPoint = touch .previousLocationInView(btnVar)
    let location : CGPoint = touch .locationInView(btnVar)
    let delta_x :CGFloat = location.x - previousLocation.x
    let delta_y :CGFloat = location.y - previousLocation.y
    btnVar.center = CGPointMake(btnVar.center.x + delta_x,
                               btnVar.center.y + delta_y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2

```
func wasDragged (buttn : UIButton, event :UIEvent){}


btn_swap.addTarget(self,action: #selector(wasDragged(buttn:event:)),for: .touchDragInside)
```